# Getting the best parameters using sklearn nested cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

Is my understanding correct that "greed_search.fit(X,Y)" has nothing with nested CV in the following code? Meaning that there is no way to get the best parameters using nested CV in sklearn.

```
    # inner cross_validation
    greed_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=estimator, param_grid=parameters, cv=inner_cv, scoring=optimized_for)
    greed_search.fit(X, optimization_label)
    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    nested_score = cross_val_score(greed_search, X=X, y=Y, cv=outer_cv)
```

Comment: What is inner_cv ? Is it a number?

Answer (score 3):

You are right: the `greed_search.fit(X, optimization_label)` in your code is performed as is without being nested into the next cross validation.

To answer your second question I ask you another question: What should be the best parameters of the grid search nested into the cross validation? The ones of the first fold? the most commons?

The inner grid search, at each step of the outer cross validation, selects the best parameters according to the training data of the current step. Hence the parameters can change among the folds. Doing the outer cross validation by yourself you can compute the best parameters of each step, but I don't think you really need it.

Comment: Great answer! But then how would you implement your final model? In other words, my understanding is that Nested CV is a tool to compare different ML algorithms when working on a specific challenge. Then, once the most promising ML algorithm has been chosen, the final model needs to be created on the original dataset. So after being done with nested CV, would one have to go through a new process of Gridsearch CV to actually become aware of the best parameters, and then apply them to a final model? If so, would this final model need to be constructed with the entire dataset or just trainingset?

Comment: @Odisseo you are completely right. Regarding the very last point: it is up to you. Once you find the best parameter, you can either i) train on the entire dataset, or ii) train on the training-set (that is something I usually prefer), or iii) use an ensemble of the best models already trained in the CV (one for each fold). Since you already trained these models during the cross validation, you may also decide to re-use them :)